# How do you access an attachment stored as MIME Part?

Tags: java, xpages, bufferedimage

It seems to me there are two ways to store an attachment in a NotesDocument.

Either as a RichTextField or as a "MIME Part".

If they are stored as RichText you can do stuff like:

document.getAttachment(fileName)

That does not seem to work for an attachment stored as a MIME Part.  See screenshot
[image]

I have thousands of documents like this in the backend. This is NOT a UI issue where I need to use the file Download control of XPages.

Each document as only 1 attachment.  An Image. A JPG file.  I have 3 databases for different sizes.  Original, Large, and Small.  Originally I created everything from documents that had the attachment stored as RichText.  But my code saved them as MIME Part. that's just what it did.  Not really my intent.

What happened is I lost some of my "Small" pictures so I need to rebuild them from the Original pictures that are now stored as MIME Part.  So my ultimate goal is to get it from the NotesDocument into a Java Buffered Image.

I think I have the code to do what I want but I just "simply" can't figure out how to get the attachment off the document and then into a Java Buffered Image.

Below is some rough code I'm working with.  My goal is to pass in the document with the original picture.  I already have the fileName because I stored that out in metaData. But I don't know how to get that from the document itself.  And I'm passing in "Small" to create the Small image.

I think I just don't know how to work with attachments stored in this manner.

Any ideas/advice would be appreciated!  Thanks!!!

```
public Document processImage(Document inputDoc, String fileName, String size) throws IOException {
    // fileName is the name of the attachment on the document
    // The goal is to return a NEW BLANK document with the image on it
    // The Calling code can then deal with keys and meta data.

// size is "Original", "Large" or "Small"
System.out.println("Processing Image,  Size = " + size);
//System.out.println("Filename = " + fileName);

boolean result = false;

Session session = Factory.getSession();
Database db = session.getCurrentDatabase();
session.setConvertMime(true);

BufferedImage img;
BufferedImage convertedImage = null;  // the output image

EmbeddedObject image = null;
InputStream imageStream = null;

int currentSize = 0;
int newWidth = 0;
String currentName = "";


try {
    // Get the Embedded Object
    image = inputDoc.getAttachment(fileName);
    System.out.println("Input Form : " + inputDoc.getItemValueString("form"));

    if (null == image) {
        System.out.println("ALERT - IMAGE IS NULL");
    }


    currentSize = image.getFileSize();
    currentName = image.getName();


    // Get a Stream of the Imahe
    imageStream = image.getInputStream();
    img = ImageIO.read(imageStream);  // this is the buffered image we'll work with
    imageStream.close();


    Document newDoc = db.createDocument();
    // Remember this is a BLANK document. The calling code needs to set the form


    if ("original".equalsIgnoreCase(size)) {
        this.attachImage(newDoc, img, fileName, "JPG");
        return newDoc;
    }

    if ("Large".equalsIgnoreCase(size)) {
        // Now we need to convert the LARGE image
        // We're assuming FIXED HEIGHT of 600px
        newWidth = this.getNewWidth(img.getHeight(), img.getWidth(), 600);
        convertedImage = this.getScaledInstance(img, newWidth, 600, false);
        this.attachImage(newDoc, img, fileName, "JPG");
        return newDoc;

    }

    if ("Small".equalsIgnoreCase(size)) {
        System.out.println("converting Small");
        newWidth = this.getNewWidth(img.getHeight(), img.getWidth(), 240);
        convertedImage = this.getScaledInstance(img, newWidth, 240, false);
        this.attachImage(newDoc, img, fileName, "JPG");
        System.out.println("End Converting Small");
        return newDoc;

    }

    return newDoc;




} catch (Exception e) {
    // HANDLE EXCEPTION HERE
    // SAMLPLE WRITE TO LOG.NSF
    System.out.println("****************");
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION IN processImage()");
    System.out.println("****************");
    System.out.println("picName: " + fileName);
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;

} finally {
    if (null != imageStream) {
        imageStream.close();
    }
    if (null != image) {
        LibraryUtils.incinerate(image);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or info about the MIME entity's headers (Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, Content-Disposition). If the content disposition = "attachment", the header contains the parameter "filename" under which you should be able to access the attachment in your NotesDocument. If the content type = "image/???" then the image is stored probably as a base64-encoded string inside the MIME entity. In this case you can use MIMEEntity.getContentAsBytes() and create the image from the byte stream (see solution from @TobySamples).

Comment: this probably won't be easy to read but that info is:
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: image/JPG
Content-Disposition: attachment;
  filename="ICEMachine_bottomsection.JPG"
Content-ID: ICEMachine_bottomsection.JPG

ICEMachine_bottomsection.JPG"

Comment: So using inputDoc.getAttachment("ICEMachine_bottomsection.JPG") returns null? If yes, what "File Name" is provided for the attachment in the $FILE field?

Comment: The $File info is:  Field Name: $FILE
Data Type: Attached Object
Data Length: 64 bytes
Seq Num: 1
Dup Item ID: 0
Field Flags: ATTACH SIGN SEAL SUMMARY 

Object Type: File
Object ID: 000116C2
Object Length: 600117
File Name: ICEMachine_bottomsection.JPG

Comment: It's strange that using inputDoc.getAttachment("ICEMachine_bottomsection.JPG") doesn't work for this document. Another approach could be to use `Vector<String> attachments = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession().evaluate("@AttachmentNames",inputDoc); EmbeddedObject image = inputDoc.getAttachment(attachments.get(0));` to get a hand on the embedded object.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it will be some variation of the following code snippet.  You might have to change which mimeentity has the content so it might be in the parent or another child depending.

```
Stream stream = session.createStream();
doc.getMIMEEntity().getFirstChildEntity().getContentAsBytes(stream);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.read());
return ImageIO.read(bais);
```

EDIT:

```
 session.setConvertMime(false);
  Stream stream = session.createStream();
  Item itm = doc.getFirstItem("ParentEntity");
  MIMEEntity me = itm.getMIMEEntity();
  MIMEEntity childEntity = me.getFirstChildEntity();
  childEntity.getContentAsBytes(stream);
  ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  stream.getContents(bo);
  byte[] mybytearray = bo.toByteArray();
  ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(mybytearray);
  return ImageIO.read(bais);
```

Comment: Toby - thanks for the reply.  I get the "concept" that your talking about.  But it doesn't like the constructor with passing stream.getBytes() into the ByteArrayStream.  stream.getBytes() actually returns an int and the constructor is expecting just bytes or some additional parameters.  ByteArrayInputStream(byte[] buf, int offset, int length)
Is that the right path?  Is there a way to convert from int to bytes?  Thanks!

Comment: stream.getBytes() just returns the length/size of the stream (=int). As in @TobySamples' code, you have to use stream.read() to get the byte array.

Comment: Ahh  Toby made an edit. the original code wasn't stream.read().  Trying this not.  I'm getting a null back so I'm trying to break apart the second line to eliminate the chaining.  but progress at least!!! yay!

Comment: Since the content disposition of the MIME entity is "attachment", there is either no content in the entity at all, or it just contains the attachment name. In both cases, the stream filled by getContentAsBytes() does not contain valid image data and hence ImageIO.read() returns null.

Comment: Sorry David, apparently my comment about updating the code didn't go through last night.

Comment: So I got back to this and pulled up some image documents that I had stored with binary encoding.  The updated code is what did the trick for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

David have a look at DominoDocument,http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/com/ibm/xsp/model/domino/wrapped/DominoDocument.html

There you can wrap every Notes document
In the DominoDocument, there such as DominoDocument.AttachmentValueHolder where you can access the attachments.
I have explained it at Engage. It very powerful
http://www.slideshare.net/flinden68/engage-use-notes-objects-in-memory-and-other-useful-java-tips-for-x-pages-development

Comment: Frank.  thanks for the idea.  I'll try this out first thing tomorrow!